# JPA using multiple database schemas at runtime dynamically

Tags: jpa, dynamic, schema

how can I set schema in run time ? 
I want run a name query in more than one database and aggregate their answers.

for example run this query in db1 and db2 :
 SELECT CUSTOMER FROM CUSTOMER CUS WHERE CUS.CODE=?1

note : I can set schema on @Table in entities ,but it isn't dynamic and i can't change it in run time.

please help!
regards

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to setup N datasources each pointing to different database/schema:

```
DataSource ds1 = // setup ds 1
DataSource ds2 = // setup ds 2
```

and N entity manager factories (EMF) with 1-to-1 mapping with each ds :

```
EntityManagerFactory emf1 = // setup emf1 mapped to ds1
EntityManagerFactory emf2 = // setup emf2 mapped to ds2
```

Then you need N copies of each DAO classes injected with each EMF :

```
public class CustomerDAO {

  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  public CustomerDAO(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
  }

  // dao methods here..
}

CustomerDAO emf1CustomerDAO = // setup customer DAO injected with emf1
CustomerDAO emf2CustomerDAO = // setup customer DAO injected with emf2
```

Your application can now make a decision at runtime which database/schema to use by selecting the DAO

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into EclipseLink's data partitioning support,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Partitioning